# How to insert headerTitle in mu TableView

Tags: tableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building a simple app in appcelerator studio.
So I want to display a TableView in my view.

this is **socialHistory.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <TableView id="table">
            <TableViewSection id="table" >
                <TableViewRow title="Apple"/>
                <TableViewRow title="Bananas"/>
            </TableViewSection>
        </TableView>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

this is **socialHistory.js**

```
var args = $.args;
//header table
var tableData = [ 
    {title: "Pippo"}, 
    {title: "Pluto"}, 
    {title: "Paperino"}, 
    {title: "Balto"} 
];

$.table.headerTitle=tableData;
```

but if I try to execute my code, I'm not able to see Header Title of my table

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to set headerTitle as headerTitle accepts only String because it is just a plain text. See [headerTitle](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-headerTitle).

What you are doing in your code will set the tableview rows not the header and also look that you have set id='table' for both table and its tableviewsection.

You seems to be learning Titanium as a beginner :), so I suggest you to please read the docs first and then try the examples in the Alloy Guide. It will help you to learn in a effective way.